# After the update to IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1, the build time of Spring Boot apps in a Docker container increased to more than double

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

My Spring Boot (Java) app is bundled in a Docker container. In IntelliJ I run and debug this app with a local run target. I use the option "Docker for Windows".

In the previous IntelliJ (< IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1 (Ultimate Edition) version the startup-time was okay (~12-15 sec.). In the current version the startup increase to 35-40 sec. My setup (Windows and Hardware) are the same.

What can I do to become a faster startup time of my app in IntelliJ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like an issue with new Gradle delegation.
Please disable "com.intellij.spring.boot.run.delegate" option in the IntelliJ registry ("Search Everywhere -> Registry...") to restore old behavior.